# Java exception not being caught

Tags: java, exception

How can this be?  Looks like plain as daylight an exception from a third party library is skipping my catch block.  Not sure where to begin troubleshooting this.  It's either me being really stupid, or me not understanding something subtle about exceptions and Java.

My console:

`Exception: org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MaxLineLimitException: Maximum line length limit exceeded; stack: org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeEntity.readRawField(MimeEntity.java:242);
org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeEntity.nextField(MimeEntity.java:258);
org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeEntity.advance(MimeEntity.java:296);
org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeTokenStream.next(MimeTokenStream.java:360);
me.unroll.scanner.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:206);
me.unroll.scanner.ScannerThread.run(ScannerThread.java:205);
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

Problem is my code looks like this:

```
try {  
//...
 for(EntityState token = messageStream.getState();
    token != EntityState.T_END_OF_STREAM;
    token = messageStream.next()) {  //this is Scanner.java:206
//...
catch(ScanComplete exc) { }
catch(MaxLineLimitException exc) { //line 282, matches "try" above
    debug("Am I getting caught?"); //no, it's not
```

I'm more

Comment: Put a debug line in the ScanComplete catch block also.

Comment: Are you sure that the log level is high enough for a `debug` to show up?

Comment: put a break point on line 283 and see if it gets hit. (the debug line)

Comment: And just as a sanity check, make sure you imported the right exception (I'm sure you are). But there's context here we can't see, because exception handling in Java pretty much works as designed. (Whether it *works*-works, different issue.)

Comment: @MattBall Even if log level is not high, I think the question is why the Exception logged on the console, when it is caught.

Comment: The error messaging your likely seeing is the inner exception. That is some error handling is unwrapping the real exception thrown. This is known as getting the "Root cause" which is usually a recursive decent of exception.getCause(). Some frameworks and servlet containers do this as a "feature". I find it annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to catch the wrong exception type.

The signature for `MimeTokenStream.next()` says it can throw `MimeException`, which you are not catching.  (BTW if you are wondering why an exception isn't being caught, you can try catching `Exception` and logging the exception type to see what is actually being thrown.)

Now, if you look at the source code for the actual source of the exception, line 242 of `MimeEntity.readRawField`, you'll see:

```
241        } catch (MaxLineLimitException e) {
242            throw new MimeException(e);
243        }
```

So even though the console message *says* `MaxLineLimitException`, the actual exception being thrown by that method is a `MimeException`.  Try catching `MimeException` in your code instead of `MaxLineLimitException`, but beware that `MimeTokenStream.next()` can probably throw `MimeException` for other reasons besides the one you've encountered.

Comment: An addendum to what @matts is that probably is some sort of root exception handling where it reports the "Root Cause" and not the wrapped exception (MimeException). That is the console is showing exeception.getCause() not just the exception.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the exception was logged, subsequently caught and not rethrown. You can put a breakpoint on the exception itself and step out from there until you reach your method.

Answer (score 1):

'Miserable Variable' is probably right. Another option is that you have the wrong MaxLineLimitException class imported.